# MongoDB how to get into file

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This is a very small question, it is just when I open a file on MongoDB it should show all the variables of the profile model that I added to every user. like this:

```
userID: lalala
serverID: lalala
coins: lalala
...
```

but instead it just says this.

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 111ms
```

when there are collections. Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Open a file? Keyboard shortcut?

Comment: To access data in MongoDB database you do a query using the `find` method as shown at [Getting started with MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/getting-started/).

Comment: I mean as in the file collections there is a file called profile models how do I see the actual items in it?